# React to event (not to state!)

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a view that observes a model (postModel):

```
struct PostView: View {
    @ObservedObject var postModel: PostModel
    @State var description: String = ""
}

class PostModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var step: Step = .first   

    enum Step {
        case first
        case second
        case third
    }
}
```

Now I want to set the state variable `description` to `""` when `step` changes from `.third` to `.first`, but not if it changes from `.second` to `.first`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want (react to events), try something like this test code. The key is to use .onReceive(...)

Edit (minor fix):

```
import SwiftUI

enum Step {
case first
case second
case third

var toString : String {
  switch self {
  case .first: return "first"
  case .second: return "second"
  case .third: return "third"
  }
}
}

class PostModel: ObservableObject {
@Published var step: Step = .first
@Published var prevStep: Step = .first
}

struct ContentView: View {

@ObservedObject var postModel = PostModel()
@State var description: String = Step.first.toString

var body: some View {
    VStack (spacing: 30) {
        Text("current step \(self.postModel.prevStep.toString)")
        Button(action: {
            switch self.postModel.step {
            case .first:  self.postModel.step = .second
            case .second: self.postModel.step = .third
            case .third:  self.postModel.step = .first
            }
        }){
            Text("change to next step")
            }.padding(30).border(Color.blue)

        Text("description: \(description)")
            .onReceive(postModel.$step) { thisStep in
                if self.postModel.prevStep == .third && thisStep == .first {
                    self.description = ""
                } else {
                    self.description = thisStep.toString
                }
                self.postModel.prevStep = thisStep
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`@Published` property wrapper already gives you a `Published.Publisher`, accessible via the `$` prefix, which will publish any time the value changes.

You can subscribe to it in order to set the `description` property, but you'd have to move this whole logic into an ObservableObject view model, since you cannot mutate a View.

The value you will receive in the subscription will be the value the step property will be set to - just *before* the value of the property actually changes, so you can compare the new value in the subscription with the existing value of the property.

```
class PostModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var step: Step = .first   
    @Published var description: String = ""

    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init() {
       self.$step.sink { nextStep in
          if nextStep == .first && self.step == .third {
             self.description = ""
          }
       }.store(in: &cancellables)
    }

    enum Step { case first, second, third }
}

struct PostView: View {
    @ObservedObject var postModel: PostModel

    var body: some Body {
       Text(postModel.description)
    }
}
```

---

*For completeness-sake*, an **alternative** approach (if you don't want to move `description` into the view model) is to create a publisher that emits a value only when it switches from `.third` to `.first`, and then subscribe to it in `.onReceive` in the View to set the `description`:

```
class PostModel: ObservableObject {
   @Published var step: Step = .first

   var newCycle: AnyPublisher<(), Never> {
      $step.compactMap { $0 == .first && self.step == .third ? () : nil }
           .eraseToAnyPublisher()
   }

   enum Step { case first, second, third }
}
```

Then, in `PostView`:

```
struct PostView: View {
   @ObservedObject var postModel: PostModel
   @State var description: String = ""

   var body: some Body {
      VStack() {
         Text(description)
      }
      .onReceive(postModel.newCycle) {
            self.description = ""
         }
   }
}
```

Comment: This approach gives me the error "Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter" for the sink closure.

Comment: Ugh.. Every time I try to simplify the example. Anyway, Views are immutable, so you can't capture self inside `sink`. So, it either needs to be done within a class (view model) or you'd need to use `.onReceive`, but then you won't have the previous value. I fixed the answer with the first variant